# How do I make my background color not disappear after one second?

Tags: html, css

Why does my background color keep disappearing? It only shows for like a second when I refresh the page and then it's not there anymore. I want it to appear over the image.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/250/250), rgb(184, 193, 248, 0.767);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="header"></section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine a background image and a color, you can use `background-blend-mode: multiply;`

I would suggest checking compatibility first.
This solution doesn't work on IE.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/250/250), rgb(184, 193, 248, 0.767);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="header"></section>
```

Answer (score 3):

An element's background images are always layered on top of background colours.

You can see a background colour through a background image if the image has transparent sections, or around the image if it doesn't fill the element or repeat.

To layer a colour over the background image you would need to create a new element or pesudo-element and position it above the image.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/250/250);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(184, 193, 248, 0.767);
}
```

```html
<section class="header"></section>
```